# Asking for clarification as to ( inductive) proof methods in metalogic. ( Comparing The Logic Book's template to a proof by Shapiro).

Tags: logic, reference-request, induction, first-order-logic, book-recommendation

- I'm currently trying to make my way through the basic metatheory of FOL reading Shapiro's entry on Classical Logic in SEP.
- Since I encounter difficulties in understanding proof procedures, I took a look at *The Logic Book* ( by Bergmann) which is recommended in the Bibliography ( at the end of Shapiro's article).
- Note : Here is an example of the kind of proof I can find in Shapiro's text ( https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#FeatSynt)

> Lemma 2. Each formula consists of a string of zero or more unary
> markers followed by either an atomic formula or a formula produced
> using a binary connective, via one of clauses (3)–(5).
>
> Proof: We proceed by induction on the complexity of the formula or, in
> other words, on the number of formation rules that are applied. The
> Lemma clearly holds for atomic formulas. Let n be a natural number,
> and suppose that the Lemma holds for any formula constructed from ***n or
> fewer*** instances of clauses (2)–(7). Let θ be a formula constructed
> from n+1 instances. The Lemma holds if the last clause used to
> construct θ was either (3), (4), or (5). If the last clause used to
> construct θ was (2), then θ is ¬ψ. Since ψ was constructed with n
> instances of the rule, the Lemma holds for ψ (by the induction
> hypothesis), and so it holds for θ. Similar reasoning shows the Lemma
> to hold for θ if the last clause was (6) or (7). By clause (8), this
> exhausts the cases, and so the Lemma holds for θ, by induction.

- In The Logic Book, I can read this

" We may now generally charaterize arguments by mathematical induction. In such an argument, we arrange the items about which we want to prove some thesis in a series of groups . In our example we arranged the sentences of Sentential Logic into the series : all sentences  contaning 0 occurrence of connectives, all sentences containing 1 occurrences..., all sentences containing 2 occurrence...
Having arranged the items in such a series , an argument by mathematical induction then takes the following form:

> (1) the thesis holds for every member of the first group of the series
>
> (2) For each group of the series, if the thesis holds for every member
> of every prior group, then it holds for every member of that group as
> well.
>
> (3) Therefore, the thesis holds for every member of every group in the
> series."

***My question(s)*** :

(1) is this the method applied by Shapiro in his proof of " lemma 2" ( reproduced above)?

(2) In The Logic Book, the method is termed " ***strong induction***" ; does Shapiro use rather ***structural induction***? ( Is " induction on the compelxity of a formula" structural inducton or strong induction, or ordinary induction? )

(3) In the inductive hypothesis of Shapiro's proof, how to understand the " ***OR FEWER***" part? If Shapiro applied stong induction, and if - in this method -  the inductive hypothesis is that the thesis ( or property) holds for ***every*** group prior to the $n^{th}$ group, shouldn't we find instead " for any formula constructed from $n$ ***AND fewer*** instances of clauses (2)–(7)"

(4) also, induction hypothesis in the template ( in he Logic Book) seems to go from group $1$, $2$, $3$ , $n-1$ to group $n$  , while Shapiro goes from  $1$, $2$, $3$ , $n$ to $n+1$.

(5) In case you had any reading recommendation regarding the uses of induction ( strong? structural? ) and *proof methods in the metalogic of FOL* , I'd be very pleased.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes. Induction on "complexity" means to apply induction on the number of *connectives*.
Base case: $0$ connectives, i.e. an *atom*.

Induction step: assume that the property to be proved holds for formulas $\varphi, \psi$ of "complexity" $n$ and consider a formula of complexity $n+1$, i.e. $\lnot \varphi$, $\varphi \lor \psi$.

(2) We use the term [structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) when we apply induction to objects that are not numbers, i.e. to some sort of recursively defined structure, such as formulas, lists, or trees.

(3) IMO it is only a question of wording (and I'm not an English native...) If we write "for any formula constructed from $n$ **and** fewer instances of clauses..." we may allude to the fact that a single formula $\varphi$ is built up applying more than one clause, which contradicts the unique readibility lemma.

(4) No issue here: if you set $k=n-1$, then $k+1=n$ and you can reconcile the two.

(5) Most mathematical logic textbooks; e.g. D.van dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&printsec=frontcover).